# If X is independent of Y, is also X independent of f(Y)

Tags: conditional-expectation

please could you help me with this?

If a random variable X is independent of Y, that is E(X|Y) = 0 , does it also hold that X will be independent of any smooth function of Y? i.e. E(X|f(Y)) = 0 ? f(Y) being a polynomial, or exponential etc.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Is the function independent of $X$? E.g we do not have things like $f(Y) = Y+X$.

Comment: The part *"that is $E(X|Y) = 0$"* is confusing. It is not a definition of independence. Counterexample: Let $Y \sim N(0,1)$, $X \sim N(0,Y)$. Then $E(X|Y) = 0$, but $X$ is not independent from $Y$.

Comment: Indeed $E(X \mid Y)=0$ is not necessary either: $X,Y$ independently $\sim N(17,4)$ would have $E(X \mid Y)=17$